# Is there a decent way to display fotos from directories?

Tags: photos, preview

I do not want to use the "Photos" app and the "Preview" app. The "Preview" app only displays one photo at a time (unless you select all of them with CMD-A). I am missing the Windows program where you simply doubleclick on the first pictures and navigate with arrow-right and arrow-left. Is there a program like this for Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two easy things come to mind:

- **QuickLook:** Just press <kbd>Space</kbd> on the first photo and then use the cursor keys to navigate
- **CoverFlow:** Press <kbd>Cmd-4</kbd> to switch the Finder window into Coverflow mode and browse through your pictures. Setting the Finder window to fullscreen might help here

Comment: QuickLook is the way I want. I figured out that I have to use up and down instead of left and right. Any way to change this? I want left and right. CoverFlow is nice, too.

Comment: Left/right works for me as well (El Capitan).

Comment: @gentlesea If you select the photos in the directory (either by using ⌘A or by selecting with the mouse), press Space, and then **click** on the QuickLook window, you will be able to use the Left and Right arrow keys to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Another reasonable solution would be to download a copy of iPhoto, (I have version 9.6.1 running on El Capitan), which has a great full screen slideshow feature, which can automaticcaly go from pic to pic or can be hand controlled with the arrow and space bar controlls. 
Photo replaced iPhoto, unless you have an old copy around. It is still supported by Apple but is no longer features, since the immensely crippled replacement, “Photo,” is favored.

Comment: Can you provide a direct download link please, http://www.heise.de/download/iphoto-1110987.html gives me a deadlink.

Comment: AFAIK you can't (legally) download iPhoto any longer

Answer (score -3):

search Mac App Store for HakView (free)

Comment: Why does this solve the OP's issue?